# Django serves file.tar.gz not compressed

Tags: python, django, download, tar

I have made a view to serve some file.tar.gz but when I download it, the file is not compressed.

Files on server, where my app is running has 63 438 bytes:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 63448 Nov  5 14:13 file.tar.gz
```

but when I download it it has 716 800 bytes.

This is my downloading function:

```
def download_logs(request):
    """ View returning file to download """
    file_path = request.GET['filepath']
    original_filename = file_path.split("/")[-1]

    try:
        file_loaded = open(file_path, 'rb')
    except IOError as err:
        LOG.debug(err)
        LOG.debug("File %s does not exist", file_path)
        return error_view(request, "IOError", "File no longer exists.")

    response = HttpResponse(file_loaded.read(), 'application/x-gzip')
    file_loaded.close()
    file_type, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(original_filename)

    if file_type is None:
        file_type = 'application/octet-stream'
    response['Content-Type'] = file_type
    response['Content-Length'] = str(os.stat(file_path).st_size)
    if encoding is not None:
        response['Content-Encoding'] = encoding

    # To inspect details for the below code, see http://greenbytes.de/tech/tc2231/
    if u'WebKit' in request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT']:
        # Safari 3.0 and Chrome 2.0 accepts UTF-8 encoded string directly.
        filename_header = 'filename=%s' % original_filename.encode('utf-8')
    elif u'MSIE' in request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT']:
        # IE does not support internationalized filename at all.
        # It can only recognize internationalized URL, so we do the trick via routing rules.
        filename_header = ''
    else:
        # For others like Firefox, we follow RFC2231 (encoding extension in HTTP headers).
        filename_header = 'filename*=UTF-8\'\'%s' % urllib.quote(original_filename.encode('utf-8'))
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; ' + filename_header
    return response
```

I image that there is a problem with the way how I open the file, I just could not find right solution.

Comment: Setting the encoding might encourage your browser to uncompress the file. To verify use the browsers debugger to see the download size and the headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Klaus D. said in comment this was a problem with encoding.

When I changed

```
if encoding is not None:
    response['Content-Encoding'] = encoding
```

to

```
response['Content-Encoding'] = 'tar'
```

Everything stated to working properly.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to serve a tar.gz file do this,

```
    tar = tarfile.open("file_name.tar.gz", "r")    
    response = HttpResponse(tar, content_type='application/tar+gzip')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="file_name.tar.gz"'
    return response
```